# grails: try throws unexpected token: try:

Tags: java, grails

Have a bit of a special one, trying to create a try catch piece of code to handle a GoogleTokenResponse and the compiler is throwing an exception error on try. Any ideas?

The error message:

```
| Loading Grails 2.2.4
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application....
| Compiling 1 source files.
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
/Users/bengtbjorkberg/Documents/grails-work/iCRM/grails-app/services/icrm/GlAuthService.groovy: 44: unexpected token: try @ line 44, column 3.
        try {
     ^
1 error
```

And the code in question

```
def setCredentila()
    HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport()
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory()
    String clientId = grailsApplication.config.googleId.glAppsId
    String clientSecret = grailsApplication.config.googleId.clientSecret
    String redirectUrl = grailsApplication.config.googleUrl.redirectURL

    try {
        GoogleTokenResponse response = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(transport, jsonFactory, clientId, clientSecret,session.code, redirectUrl).execute()
    } catch (GoogleTokenResponseException e) {
    if (e.getDetails() != mull){
        log.error e.getDetails().getError()
        if (e.getDetails().getErrorDescription() != null) {
            log.error e.getDetails().getErrorDescription()
          }
          if (e.getDetails().getErrorUri() != null) {
            log.error e.getDetails().getErrorUri()
          }
        } else {
          log.error e.getMessage()
        }
    }


}
GoogleCredential accessToken = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret).setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setTransport(transport).build().setAccessToken(response.getAccessToken()).setRefreshToken(response.getRefreshToken());
session.accessToken = accessToken
```

}

Comment: Maybe a typo, but `def setCredentila()` should be `def setCredentila(){`

Comment: It was a typo, but there where two other issues as well:) First is that it is TokenResponseException not GoogleTokenResponseException, or at least I think so still not working satisfactory. Second was that I got quite lost in the squarely bracket count

Comment: So... Is it OK now ? Can you update your code and tell what's wrong now ?

Answer (score 1):

So, after mopping about a bit I managed to resolve all the issues, the one that threw the unexpected token was just me forgetting to put the squirly brackets in the right place. Another issue was that I had indeed misspelt setCredential,  which I would more than likely have noticed next. There was also an issue with `GoogleTokenResponseException` which should be `TokenResponseException`.

Here is the full setCredential code to generate a token for google oauth2 callback:

```
def setCredential( HttpSession session ) {
    HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport()
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory()
    String clientId = grailsApplication.config.googleId.glAppsId
    String clientSecret = grailsApplication.config.googleId.glClientSecret
    String redirectUrl = grailsApplication.config.googleUrl.glRedirectUrl
    log.info "Requesting key for client Id: " + clientId
    log.debug "Client Secret: " + clientSecret
    log.debug "redurectUrl: " + redirectUrl
    try {
        GoogleTokenResponse response = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(transport, jsonFactory, clientId, clientSecret,session.code, redirectUrl).execute()
        log.debug "Access token: " + response.getAccessToken()
        GoogleCredential accessToken = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret).setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setTransport(transport).build().setAccessToken(response.getAccessToken()).setRefreshToken(response.getRefreshToken());
        session.accessToken = response.getAccessToken()
        glAuth = true

    } catch (TokenResponseException e) {
        if (e.getDetails() != null){
            log.error "TokenResponseException Detials:" + e.getDetails().getError()
            if (e.getDetails().getErrorDescription() != null) {
                log.error "TokenResponseException descipriton" + e.getDetails().getErrorDescription()
            }
            if (e.getDetails().getErrorUri() != null) {
                log.error "TokenResponseException Error Url" +e.getDetails().getErrorUri()
            }
        } else {
            log.error "TokenResponseException Message" +e.getMessage()
        }
    }
}
```

Where the variables in config are

```
grailsApplication.config.googleId.glAppsId          
//Contains the Application if, format 0000000000.apps.googleusercontent.com
grailsApplication.config.googleId.glClientSecret
//The secret from google API console
grailsApplication.config.googleUrl.glRedirectUrl
//The redirection Url, not certain why it needs its, but it gets awfully upset if it does not.
```

glAuth and session.accessToken may need to be set outside of catch

The only thing I did not managed to giure out was where to pick up the browser error code (or is ti http error code, the 200 OK 400 Authentication error)